# C++: How to iterate over a list of class types for typeid verification and downcasting?

Tags: c++, types, derived-class, downcast, typeid

I would like to perform a down casting at execution time.

For what I read, if I want to do it, I need to compare the `typeid` of my polymorphic pointer with those of my derived classes, then do the casting in the correct type.

Plus, let's assume that I have a large number of derived classes.
This implies I have to write a long `switch` or list of `if`.

I would like to reduce this effort by using a list of classes to check.

This could look like:

```
#include <string.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <vector>
#include <map>

using namespace std;

class BaseShapes
{
        virtual int run() = 0;
};

class ClassRectangle : public BaseShapes
{
        int run()
        {
            std::cout << "I am a Rectangle. " << std::endl;
            return 0;
        }

        float get_length () {return 12.4;};
        float get_width() {return 6.2;};
};

class ClassCircle : public BaseShapes
{
        int run()
        {
            std::cout << "I am a Cricle. " << std::endl;
            return 0;
        }

        float get_diameter() {return 5.3;};
};

float function_only_for_Rectangle(ClassRectangle *rectangle)
{
   // a function coming from a library that I cannot touch and that requires a derived type.
   // But for the example I do something dummy!
   return rectangle->get_length()
};

auto downcast_function (auto *p)
{
    enum ListOfTypes {
        ClassCircle,
        ClassRectangle,
        // and a lot more differents classes
    };

    for ( int fooInt = ClassCircle; fooInt < ClassRectangle; fooInt++ )
    {
        ListOfTypes fooItem = static_cast<ListOfTypes>(fooInt);
        if (typeid(p) == typeid(fooItem))
        {
            auto pCasted =dynamic_cast<fooItem>(p);
            return pCasted;
        }
    }
    
    std::cout<< "downcast_function warning: no typeid is matching !" << std::endl;
    return p;
};

int main(void) 
{ 
    // Beginning of main.
    cout << "(Start)" << endl;
    
        std::unique_ptr<BaseShapes> Shape1(new ClassRectangle());
        auto p=Shape1.get();
        //function_only_for_Rectangle(p); // not working since p is of type BaseShapes*
        auto pbis=downcast_function(p); // should be of type ClassRectangle*
        function_only_for_Rectangle(pbis);
    
    // End of the main.
    cout << "(End) " << endl;   
    return 0; 
} 
// EoF
```

So how can I write the `downcast_function` ? Or in other words, how can I iterate over a list of class types in order to make a `typeid` comparison and a casting ?

## More details:

I agree that in this dummy example, I could simply override a function for each derived class and that is a much better way to deal with polymorphism. But I need to downcast, this is a constrain coming from a more complex problem where they are things that I am not allowed to changed. So, the question here is not why downcast but how.

To give a bit more details about my constrains are:

1. To start from a base pointer.
2. Get a derived pointer and give it to an external function (here called `function_only_for_Rectangle`, so I cannot modify this function).
3. I cannot do a simple and direct `dynamic_cast<ClassRectangle>(p)` because the type of `p` (or equivalently `Shape1`) will change at running time. This means that `Shape1` can have "randomly" any derived type from `BaseShapes`. So I need something "automatic" and this is why I was thinking about iterate over all derived types and downcast according to the `typeid` match (but I am open to better ideas).

All the classes can modified if needed.

Comment: You don't do like that at all, you just iterate over the base objects and call its virtual functions, and let the compiler and run-time polymorphism do its "magic".

Comment: A function can only have 1 return-type, and it has to be known at compile-time. Using `auto` just means you don't need to specify what the type is yourself, the compiler will do it for you.

Comment: Why do you believe you need to do any downcasting? You already have an abstract interface.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude I edited my question, I think that this edit replies to your comments: I cannot do pure polymorphism (I would like to but it is not coming from me).

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ I edited my question and gave more details about the reasons why I think I need to downcast even if I have an abstract interface. But I am open to any ideas to solve my problem without downcasting.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You say "polymorphic" but what you want to do is the opposite of it.

Instead of trying to work against polymorphism you could actually use it. If all subclasses have their own implementation of a virtual function then the caller does not need to care what the actual dynamic type of the object is. That is runtime polymorphism in a nutshell.

I suppose the naming for `run` is only for the example. Give it a better name, supply a default implementation in the base class, implement specific behavior in `ClassRectangle` and let the caller call it. No need to cast.

```
class BaseShapes
{
        virtual int do_something_rectangly() { return 0;}
        ~virtual BaseShapes() = default;
};

class ClassRectangle : public BaseShapes
{
        int do_something_rectangly() override
        {
            std::cout << "I am a Rectangle. " << std::endl;
            return 0;
        }
};

class ClassCircle : public BaseShapes
{
    // does not override do_something_rectangly()
};

int function_for_any_base_shape(BaseShapes& s)
{
   return s.do_something_rectangly();
};

int main(void) 
{ 
    // Beginning of main.
    cout << "(Start)" << endl;
    
    std::unique_ptr<BaseShapes> Rec1(new ClassRectangle());
    function_for_any_base_shape(*pbis);
    
    cout << "(End) " << endl;   
    return 0; 
}
```

---

Concerning your edit:

> 3. I cannot do a simple and direct dynamic_cast(p) because the type of p (or equivalently Shape1) will change at running time. This means that Shape1 can have "randomly" any derived type from BaseShapes. [...]

Either I misunderstand what you wrote completely or you misunderstand how `dynamic_cast` works. `dynamic_cast` does already check what the dynamic type of the object is:

```
BaseShapes* b1 = new ClassCircle;
if(ClassRectangle* d = dynamic_cast<ClassRectangle*>(b1))
{
    // cast is sucessfull
    function_only_for_Rectangle(d);
} else {
    // dynamic type of b1 is not ClassRectangle
}
```

To call `function_only_for_Rectangle` you do not need to be able to cast to all subtypes of `ClassBase`. You only need to `dynamic_cast` to a pointer to `ClassRectangle` and check if the cast was sucesfull.

Comment: I edited my question. I agree with you in a general case, it is much better to do it this way. But I have no choice here to downcast to make things coming from the "outside" compatible. So, in that sense your answer is not answering my problem, even if it offer a better generic solution.

Comment: @R.N I know that this is a non-answer. I was planning to add something for the actual question. A poor mans polymorphism is an `enum subtype` and a virtual `subtype getType()` or something along this line

Comment: @R.N however, your example is not a good example for the question in the title (because there is no apparent need to cast). Please clarify in the question what you can change and what you cannot change on the code

Comment: OK, I edited my question. I hope it is clearer and you have enough to think about a solution.

Comment: @R.N sorry, but it is still not clear why you think you need something like your `downcast_function`. You can use `dynamic_cast` when you want to call `function_only_for_rectangle` only for rectangles

Comment: Using `dynamic_cast<ClassRectangle>` directly then calling `function_only_for_rectangle` is possible when you know at compilation time the class you want to downcast into. While I will know it at runtime, this is why I need something "automatic". I admit that my example is not emphasizing this need for an automatic downcast, but I don't know how to do it in a minimal example.

Comment: @R.N your question is asking how to call `function_only_for_rectangle` with only rectangles. If you actually wanted to ask something different you should open a new question, this one is very unclear and honestly I don't think it can be fixed. Whatever function `foo( some_sub_type*)` you want to call, once you call it you know what type it expects as parameter and can cast to that, hence it is not clear what problem you are trying to solve

Comment: @R.N in the quesiton you say that the type of the object can change "randomly" now you say that the type of the functions parameter can change, thats two completely different situation. Don't get me wrong, i am not complaining, just trying to explain why it is difficult to give an answer. What you actually need is unclear

Comment: I get your point. My bad if it is not clear, but it is also because we are getting further away from my question. To make it simple: starting from your edited answer "if(ClassRectangle* d = dynamic_cast<ClassRectangle*>(b1)) ...", how can I do a list a conditional testing like this one in a for loop over all my derived classes ?

Comment: @R.N from the top of my head I dont know a way to loop that would not be much more complicated than simply doing the dynamic cast manually for each derived type.

Comment: @R.N the problem with your `downcast_function` approach is that the return type must be known at compile time but you only know the dynamic type of the object at runtime, hence it cannot work that way

Comment: Well I could include the `function_only_for_rectangle` in the `downcast_function` if the downcast is successful. But, if this kind of loop is not possible then it makes no sense anymore. I suppose I just can't be lazy on this one...